# Assigning result of Integer.parseInt to char primitive

Tags: java, char

The statement

```
char c = 10;
```

compiles fine, but

```
char d = Integer.parseInt("10");
```

results in compilation error

> "Type Mismatch cannot convert from int to char".

What is the difference between the two statements?

Answer (score 4):

This is documented in the Java Language Specification Section 5.2 Assignment Contexts:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is
>     representable in the type of the variable.

`10` is a constant expression and 10 is representable in `char` (`char` can store 0~65535), so the conversion from `int` to `char` is allowed. `Integer.parseInt("10")` is not a constant expression (it has to be evaluated at runtime), so a conversion from `int` to `char` is not allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` is not a `char`. They are two different primitive types in java. An int is of `32bit` and a char is of `8bit`.

When you do

```
char d = Integer.parseInt("10");
```

you are parsing a `string` "10" to an `int` and then you are trying to assign it to a char which won't work unless you specify the downcast explicitly. Since there is a loss of precision the compiler complains and asks you to explicitly downcast it. Downcast it as shown below :

```
char d = (char) Integer.parseInt("10");
```

In the first statement,

```
char c = 10;
```

the value 10 is within the range of a `char`. The range being from (0 - 65,536) unsigned, so there is no issue. Suppose the value is greater than this you would get the same issue.

Comment: You might mention that the compiler can check in the case of a literal, so it would actually complain about `char c = 12334567;` Since there's no way to be sure about an arbitrary int, it always complains.

Answer (score 1):

In JLS 5.2 section:

> **Assignment contexts** allow the value of an expression to be assigned (§15.26) to a variable
>
> if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte,
>   short, **char**, or int:
>   • A **narrowing primitive conversion** may be used if
>   the type of the variable is byte, short, or **char**, and **the value of the
>   constant expression is representable in the type of the variable**

And what is a `constant expression`:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting **a value of primitive
>   type** or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using
>   only the following...

So, IMHO,
In `char c=10;`, a `constant expression` of type `int` is assigned to a variable of type `char`, and a `narrowing primiteve conversion` is happening.

Whileas in `char d= Integer.parseInt("10");`, an `int` value is returned by `Integer.parseInt()` which has `32` bits, and it will exceed the `16` bits limits of the `char` type, so it complains about it and ask for a explicict downcast.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that an `int` has a much larger capacity than a `char`.

1. Your first example compiles because the compiler only lets implicit conversions take place if it is 100% certain that the conversion will succeed; the compiler knows `10` from `int` to `char` will succeed. on the other hand, say it was  `char c=101111;` doesn't compile...
2. Your second example doesn't compile because `Integer.parseInt("10")` generates the value at runtime and the compiler cannot tell what value will be assigned to `d` hence an explicit cast is required for it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

In first one you are assigning the character value `10` to the character. If you print the character it will print a new line. Because new line's character values is `10`

But in 2nd one you are trying to assign a `Integer` `Object` to the `char` which is not possible. You can only assign a real character or a character value to the char

For an example

```
char c='A';
char c=65;
```

Both these two will print `A` because the character value of `A` is `65`

Please refer this [link](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) also for more info

Answer (score 0):

In this we are converting a string to an int and then trying to assign that Integer to a character.That is why it results in error

char d = Integer.parseInt("10");

To eliminate the error you will need to typecast it to char i.e.

char d=(char)Integer.parseInt("10");